# How to pass query parameters value from the csv file to restapi using python

Tags: python, rest

I've below codes to collect the json output from my storage device by using restAPI.
The code is working fine when I pass 2 query parameters (portId and hostGroupName) manually, but currently I want to pass all value from csv file to the query parameters and combine all output under the same json structure. Is is possible to do that? Thanks

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
import requests

path = Path(r"C:\Python\Code")

url = "http://192.168.1.30:23451/ConfigurationManager/v1/objects/storages/800000010888/host-wwns"
pwd = "129yZm1vhjqidGFzc3dvcmRAZW50MQ=="
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + pwd
}

params = {
    "portId": "CL3-C",
    "hostGroupName": "expdb1a"

    ##### Expected to take value from list.csv file and pass it to below query parameters ######
    "portId": "portID from list.csv",
    "hostGroupName": "hostGroupName from list.csv"
    ##########################################################################################
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
stg = response.json()
json_data_w = json.dumps(stg, indent=2)

Path(path/"output.json").write_text(json_data_w)


list.csv
portId,hostGroupName
CL3-C,expdb1a
CL4-C,expdb1a
CL3-A,expdb2a
CL4-A,expdb2a
CL3-E,expapp1a
CL4-E,expapp1a
CL3-J,expapp2a
CL4-J,expapp2a


Example of output.json I pass query parameters manually:
{
  "data" : [ {
    "hostWwnId" : "CL3-C,10,c050760996aa003a",
    "portId" : "CL3-C",
    "hostGroupNumber" : 10,
    "hostGroupName" : "expdb1a",
    "hostWwn" : "1090384996aa003a",
    "wwnNickname" : "expdb1a_v1"
  }, {
    "hostWwnId" : "CL3-C,10,c050760996aa003b",
    "portId" : "CL3-C",
    "hostGroupNumber" : 10,
    "hostGroupName" : "expdb1a",
    "hostWwn" : "1090384996aa003b",
    "wwnNickname" : "expdb1a_v2"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this:

```
with open('list.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines() #list of portId,hostGroupName

json_list = []
for l in lines[1:]: #start at 1 to skip headers
     # print(l.split(',')[0],l.split(',')[1] )
     params = {
        "portId": l.split(',')[0],
        "hostGroupName": l.split(',')[1]
        }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    stg = response.json()
    json_data_w = json.dumps(stg, indent=2)
    json_list.append(json_data_w)
    
Path(path/"output.json").write_text(json_list) #this writes a list of your json outputs
```

Comment: Hello Jonathan, Thanks for your suggestion!!, it work like a charm and now I'm able to combine all output together.